# Node.js with Socket.io on multiple pages?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq

I am building an app with Node.js that will have multiple pages and will be setup like so:

- Page1 : Default home
- Page2 : Connects to RabbitMQ and gets data then pushes it to the client via Socket.io.
- Page3: Same thing as Page2 except it pushes different data and subscribes to different data on RabbitMQ.

Is it possible to have Page2 subscribe to RabbitMQ and use Socket.io if Page1 does not?

Also will Page2 and Page3 conflict with each other since they are both using socket.io and RabbitMQ?

I have the RabbitMQ and Socket.io code working in a stand-alone app but am confused on how to do this in an app with multiple pages/routes. (I am using Express for the routing.)

I'm very new to Node.js so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. Was thinking about it incorrectly.

When NodeJs starts (or on the first subscriber) the system should connect to RabbitMQ and emit events on Socket.io regardless of the page the user is on. It's the page that determines what topic the user wants to listen to via the connect code to socket.io. This way there is only one instance the of the RabbitMQ code ever running and the server can emit to anyone interested. And this way there is no conflict.